# JQuery - Do Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

**Hello**, I've tried created simple animations like this video, what I need that when the user click on car modal button animation the current car to out then animation the car next to in, And How To make this responsive.

Here Video about what I need:

[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kirVMzahuTo&feature=youtu.be)

**Here my Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.wheelEleContainer .slectWheel').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var getImgWheel = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        $('.car .wheelInCar').css('background-image',
            'url(' + getImgWheel + ')'
            );
    });
    $('.click.car-2').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.car-image.car-2').addClass('current');

    });
})
```

```css
.car{
    height:600px;
    padding:40px 0;
    background-color:#efefef;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.car .click{
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #0094ff;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
.car-image {
    position:absolute;
    top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    -moz-transform: translate(160%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(160%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(160%, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(160%, 0);
    transform: translate(160%, 0);
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
.car .car-image.current {
    -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
    -o-transform: translate(0,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
    transform: translate(0,0);
    display:block;
}
.car .car-image .wheelInCar{
    width:99px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    -webkit-animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
    animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
}
.car .car-image .wheelInCar.left{
    background-image:url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740531661.png');
    top:94px;
    left:98px;
}
.car .car-image .wheelInCar.right{
    background-image:url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740544512.png');
    top:94px;
    right:75px;
}
.car .wheelEleContainer{
    cursor:pointer;
}
@keyframes wheelRotating {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }

    to {
       -moz-transform: rotate(0);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0);
        -o-transform: rotate(0);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="car-button-container">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="click car-1">
                            Car Model 1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="click car-2">
                            Car Model 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="click">
                            Car Model 3
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-s-6">
                        <div class="click">
                            Car Model 4
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="car-image current car-1">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727111161.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="wheelInCar left"></div>
                        <div class="wheelInCar right"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="car-image car-2">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727122822.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="wheelInCar left"></div>
                        <div class="wheelInCar right"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="car-image">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727131353.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="wheelInCar left"></div>
                        <div class="wheelInCar right"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="car-image">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727151114.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="wheelInCar left"></div>
                        <div class="wheelInCar right"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="wheelEleContainer">
                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="slectWheel">
                            <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740561243.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <div class="slectWheel">
                            <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/14899275127831.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <div class="slectWheel">
                            <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740580684.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Run my code in full snippet to see problem**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add index to your cars and car models to keep the thing simple. Then you should modify the "click" callback to add the animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wheelEleContainer .slectWheel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var getImgWheel = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.car .wheelInCar').css('background-image',
      'url(' + getImgWheel + ')'
    );
  });
  var running = false;
  $('.car-model').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $(this).data("index");

    var $pre = $('.car-image.current');
    var $dom = $('.car-image[data-car-index="' + index + '"]');
    if ($dom.hasClass("current") || running) {
      return;
    }
    running = true;
    $dom.addClass('current');
    $pre.addClass('left').removeClass('current');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $pre.addClass('no-transition');
      $pre.removeClass('left');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $pre.removeClass('no-transition');
        running = false;
      }, 100);
    }, 2100);

  });
})
```

```css
.car {
  height: 600px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  background-color: #efefef;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.car .click {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #0094ff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.car-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  transform: translate(calc(50vw + 400px), 0);
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  //width:50vw;
}

.car .car-image.current {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  display: block;
}

.car .car-image.left {
  transform: translate(calc(-50vw - 400px), 0);
  display: block;
}

.car .car-image.no-transition {
  transition: none;
}

.car .car-image .wheelInCar {
  width: 99px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
  animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
}

.car .car-image .wheelInCar.left {
  background-image: url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740531661.png');
  top: 94px;
  left: 98px;
}

.car .car-image .wheelInCar.right {
  background-image: url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740544512.png');
  top: 94px;
  right: 75px;
}

.car .wheelEleContainer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes wheelRotating {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="car">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="car-button-container">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <div class="click car-model" data-index="1">
            Car Model 1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <div class="click car-model" data-index="2">
            Car Model 2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <div class="click car-model" data-index="3">
            Car Model 3
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-s-6">
          <div class="click car-model" data-index="4">
            Car Model 4
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-2">
        <div class="car-image current" data-car-index="1">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727111161.png" alt="" />
          <div class="wheelInCar left"></div>
          <div class="wheelInCar right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="car-image" data-car-index="2">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727122822.png" alt="" />
          <div class="wheelInCar left"></div>
          <div class="wheelInCar right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="car-image" data-car-index="3">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727131353.png" alt="" />
          <div class="wheelInCar left"></div>
          <div class="wheelInCar right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="car-image" data-car-index="4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727151114.png" alt="" />
          <div class="wheelInCar left"></div>
          <div class="wheelInCar right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="wheelEleContainer">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2">
          <div class="slectWheel">
            <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740561243.png" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
          <div class="slectWheel">
            <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/14899275127831.png" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
          <div class="slectWheel">
            <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740580684.png" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but there are a problem in your code that if the user is click on the same button more than once the animation will be disappear.

Comment: and how to make this is responsive we know that translate by percent will get from the element width not the parent

Comment: @MohamedHassn  I updated the answer fixing the bug, adding responsive. I don't know what kind of responsive do u want, if it's not what u want, pls describe your need.

Comment: Thank you very much Please, But Could you Help me I've some problemes

Comment: @MohamedHassn just ask then

Comment: so I need to stop wheel rotation when animation of current car finished, also I need the car move natural .. with some ease .. slow down before it stops and take some angle .. and when its going out it take some angle up then speed up like this video:
[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-j2MC59V3oo&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: and when car is in screen use this transition:
[easing In](http://easings.net/#easeOutQuart) 
and when car is go to out screen use this transition:
[easing out](http://easings.net/#easeInQuart)

Comment: wow... There are some many things u need. U can't just rely on stackoverflow to build the whole of your application.  Why not try to read some documents yourself? http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: I'm New to Jquery and I practice

Comment: Yeah, I can understand. But it's a fact that u must solve ur multiple specific problems yourself. Or find someone nearby that want to write lots of free code for u.

Comment: sorry for you  why you refuse to help me

Comment: We guys just have interest in small problems or difficult problems, but have no interest in big and boring problems. BTW, the "slow down before it stops and take some angle"  is somehow interesting. U can ask about this problem in another question, I believe that there will be some people willing to help to.

Comment: you are right, I know the solution but I'm not sure the solution of my problem is using CSS Keyframes :)

Comment: I will be happy if helped me in this question:
[stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896006/jquery-animation-using-keyframes)