# Jquery Animation using keyframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Hello** I've Created simple animation but I'd like to add some effects like this video that after the car come in stop rotation of the wheel and the car speed will be slow and if the car start to leave, run rotation of the wheel and the car speed will be fast:

[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Nbm9D0ThEs&feature=youtu.be)

**Here the code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.wheelEleContainer .slectWheel').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var getImgWheel = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        $('.car .wheelInCar').css('background-image',
          'url(' + getImgWheel + ')'
        );
    });
    var running = false;
    $('.car-model').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var index = $(this).data("index");

        var $pre = $('.car-image.current');
        var $dom = $('.car-image[data-car-index="' + index + '"]');
        if ($dom.hasClass("current") || running) {
            return;
        }
        running = true;
        $dom.addClass('current');
        $pre.addClass('left').removeClass('current');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $pre.addClass('no-transition');
            $pre.removeClass('left');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $pre.removeClass('no-transition');
                running = false;
            }, 100);
        }, 2100);

    });
})
```

```css
.car{
    height:600px;
    padding:40px 0;
    background-color:#efefef;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.car .click{
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #0094ff;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
.car-image {
    position:absolute;
    top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    -moz-transform: translate(160%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(160%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(160%, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(160%, 0);
    transform: translate(160%, 0);
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
.car .car-image.current {
    -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
    -o-transform: translate(0,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
    transform: translate(0,0);
    display:block;
    animation-name:comIn;
    animation-duration:2s;
}
.car .car-image.left {
    -moz-transform: translate(-160%,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-160%,0);
    -o-transform: translate(-160%,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-160%,0);
    transform: translate(-160%,0);
    display:block;
}
.car .car-image.no-transition {
    transition:none;
}
.car .car-image .wheelInCar{
    width:99px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    -webkit-animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
    animation: wheelRotating 2s linear infinite;
}
.car .car-image .wheelInCar.left{
    background-image:url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740531661.png');
    top:94px;
    left:98px;
}
.car .car-image .wheelInCar.right{
    background-image:url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740544512.png');
    top:94px;
    right:75px;
}
.car .wheelEleContainer{
    cursor:pointer;
}
@keyframes comIn {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0);
        -o-transform: rotate(0);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
        transform: rotate(0);
    }

    80% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
        transform: rotate(-10deg);
    }
    100%{
        -moz-transform: rotate(0);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0);
        -o-transform: rotate(0);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
}

@keyframes wheelRotating {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }

    to {
       -moz-transform: rotate(0);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0);
        -o-transform: rotate(0);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
 <div class="car">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="car-button-container">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="click car-model" data-index="1">
                            Car Model 1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="click car-model" data-index="2">
                            Car Model 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="click car-model" data-index="3">
                            Car Model 3
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="click car-model" data-index="4">
                            Car Model 4
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="car-image current" data-car-index="1">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727111161.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="wheelInCar left"></div>
                        <div class="wheelInCar right"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="car-image" data-car-index="2">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727122822.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="wheelInCar left"></div>
                        <div class="wheelInCar right"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="car-image" data-car-index="3">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727131353.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="wheelInCar left"></div>
                        <div class="wheelInCar right"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="car-image" data-car-index="4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727151114.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="wheelInCar left"></div>
                        <div class="wheelInCar right"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="wheelEleContainer">
                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="slectWheel">
                            <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740561243.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <div class="slectWheel">
                            <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/14899275127831.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <div class="slectWheel">
                            <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740580684.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: your required output is a video?

Comment: yes it's what I need

Comment: well ... make a video then, you don't need javascript for that

Comment: sorry you didn't understood Me What I need Code to do animation like in the video.
thank you

Comment: You will need to narrow this down to a specific question. As it stands, you're asking us to QA your project and also provide fixes for anything that we find.

Comment: Please if you could help me :)

Comment: I don't think it's such complicated. However modifying the provided code to make a working version is not simple. Redesigning it is also not something we can do in our free time (it's some kind of complete project feature). So you can see the importance of design. When it goes wrong, it's hard to fix it, and redesigning also sometimes requires extra effort.